# How to calculate average number of actions in selected month per client in Teradata SQL?

Tags: sql, average, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have table with transactions in Teradata SQL like below:

```
ID   | trans_date
-------------------
123  | 2021-09-15
456  | 2021-10-20
777  | 2021-11-02
890  | 2021-02-14
...  | ...
```

And I need to calculate average number of transactions made by clients in month: 09, 10 and 11, so as a result I need something like below:

```
Month  | Avg_num_trx
--------------------------------------------------------
09     | *average number of transactions per client in month 09*
10     | *average number of transactions per client in month 10*
11     | *average number of transactions per client in month 11*
```

How can I do taht in Teradata SQL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not as familiar with Teradata, you could probably start by extracting the month from the trans_date, then grouping id and month and adding in count(id). From there you could group month by avg(count_id). Something like this -

```
WITH extraction AS(
SELECT 
 ID,
 EXTRACT (MONTH FROM trans_date) AS MM
FROM your_table)

,

WITH id_counter AS(
SELECT
 ID,
 MM,
 COUNT(ID) as id_count
FROM extraction
GROUP BY ID, MM)

SELECT
 MM,
 AVG(id_count) AS Avg_num_trx
FROM id_counter
ORDER BY MM;
```

The first CTE grabs month from trans_date.
The second CTE groups ID and month with count(ID) - should give you the total actions in that month for that client ID as id_count.
The final table gets the average of id_count grouped by month, which should be the average interactions per client for the period.

If EXTRACT doesn't work for some reason you could also try STRTOK(trans_date, '-', 2).

Other potential methods to replace -

```
--current
EXTRACT (MONTH FROM trans_date) AS MM

--option 1
STRTOK(trans_date, '-', 2) AS MM

--option 2
LEFT(RIGHT(trans_date, 5),2) AS MM
```

Above reworked as subqueries - should help with debugging -

```
SELECT
 MM,
 AVG(id_count) AS Avg_num_trx
FROM (SELECT
       ID,
       MM,
       COUNT(ID) as id_count
       FROM (SELECT 
              ID,
              EXTRACT (MONTH FROM trans_date) AS MM
              FROM your_table) AS a
       GROUP BY ID, MM) AS b
ORDER BY MM;
```

Comment: Are you sure this answer? I have error that "Object extraction does not exist" ;/

Comment: procopypaster, could you show me modified version of your answer witj STRTOK instead of extraction? because extraction does not work :/

Comment: This article - https://docs.teradata.com/r/kmuOwjp1zEYg98JsB8fu_A/SIkE2wnHyQBnU4AGWRZSRw - indicates EXTRACT should work. If it doesn't you could try the STRTOK method or a variation of TRIM/RTRIM/LTRIM. You really just need some way to isolate the month, it shouldn't matter as much how as long as the data  structure is consistent.

Comment: no, no, no I mean that this query can not find table with name "extraction", the error is here: "FROM extraction"

Comment: procopypaster, I understand, but the problem is not in EXTRACT function, the problem is that source table with name "extraction" is not find by the Teradata

Comment: did you swap out where I put 'FROM your_table' to the actual name of the table you're pulling from? Sounds like it may not be creating the table. You could try that part of the query on it's own as well to see what errors it's giving to troubleshoot- so just the 'SELECT ID, EXTRACT (MONTH FROM trans_date) AS month FROM your_table' section

Comment: Yes, I changed "your_table" to my real table, I checked also this part of code: 'SELECT ID, EXTRACT (MONTH FROM trans_date) AS month FROM your_table' (using of course my data) and this line works good

Comment: So error could be after coma and "id_counter...

Comment: one second - going to put in another update. I think the issue may be a result of month being a reserved word in Teradata.

Comment: yes, I know that I changed your "month" to month1 in my modified query

Comment: I do not understand, why table id_counter can not take data from table extraction

Comment: I converted the CTE statements to a subquery which should help debug, or at least work around whatever reason the CTEs weren't working.

Comment: So if I add condition that trans_date between for example '2021-09-01' and '2021-11-30' I will have average number of transaction in month 09,10 and 11 yes ?

Comment: ufff it works, it was really hard and stressed, thank you, I gave best answer !

Comment: it should, you would want to add that on to the subquery that uses 'your_table' if you want to get date specific.

Answer (score 0):

This will return the expected answer:

```
SELECT 
   Extract (MONTH From trans_date) AS MM,
   Cast(Count(*) AS FLOAT) / Count(DISTINCT id)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY MM
```

Compare to @procopypaster's answer too see which one is more efficient for your data.